# Index all keys of a location in Firebase

Tags: indexing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose this data structure:

```
{
     client: {
         firstName: "John",
         lastName: "Doe"
     }
}
```

I know that I can index searching on `firstName` and `lastName` by doing:

```
{
    rules: {
        client: {
            .indexOn: ["firstName", "lastName"]
        }
    }
}
```

But, suppose I want to add `email` or `gender` field to my data later on. Is there any way to write a wild card rule to index on all fields of `client`? I'm thinking something like this syntax:

```
// this does not work
{
    rules: {
        client: {
            .indexOn: ["*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not in docs - it's not exist. So no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell the database to create an index on all fields. Indexes come at a performance cost, which is why we want you to explicitly choose which indexes you'll need. Providing a wildcard operator would defeat the purpose.